# .net mvc 4 using razor and json

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on a .NET MVC 4 project. We have a razor list of items, the razor handles number of items shown and the ordering. We want to then make this client side. Is there a way we can update the razor via json to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: Mind showing us the code? Ajax calls might work.

Comment: A lot of tags in your title, but no question. Please remove the tags and set the title to something meaningful.

Comment: Do you want to order the numbers client side with jQuery instead of server side with .net? By passing the numbers via JSON to the client?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way we can update the razor via json to achieve this?

No.

Razor syntax is rendered during the request of the page (server side). There is no razor when it comes to client side, so you cannot modify it from client side. And if you could the server would need to re-render it anyway.

You could use AJAX to request a new list of objects (which you could return as JSON), and then you could update your HTML using javascript to reflect that new list. But this is a different question, and you would need to try something for yourself first anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For client side ordering,paging and filtering I would suggest using a Jquery Grid such as https://datatables.net/

Another option for you may be [Kendo Grid](http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

Ive had good experiences with both, although I prefer Kendo as it is a little cleaner when you do not need to do too many crazy things with custom HTML column values.